# Calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{(x+b)^2}dx,|a|<1,b>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

Calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{(x+b)^2}dx,|a|<1,b>0$
So I thought setting $f(z)=\frac{e^{aLog(z)}}{(z+b)^2}$ and using keyhole contour to calculate.
I managed to show that the integrals on the bigger and smaller circle are going to 0
but I got into trouble when i tried to set $z=re^{ai(2\pi-\epsilon)}$ and then plugging it into $f$
$f(re^{ai(2\pi-\epsilon)})=\frac{r^ae^{ai(2\pi-\epsilon)}}{(r^{i(2\pi-\epsilon)}+b)^2}=r^af(z)$(when $\epsilon\to 0$  )
but when I take $r\to\infty$ to calculate the integrals it doesn't make sense.
I'm supposed to calculate it with keyhold contour and then Residue Theorem

[image]

Comment: The residue would be outside of the contour, so I don't think you can use Residue Theorem here unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: added a photo :)

Comment: Isn't that from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: no this is the contour that i was asked to calculate on

Comment: You've asked this question before and many people gave you good answers. The counter you draw works. An easier adjustment is to slant the two  lines at an angle, say $\alpha>0$.and $-\alpha$respectively You will let $R\rightarrow\infty$, $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$ and $\alpha\rightarrow0$. There is a little trick, not to difficult to get on your own. You may look at Marden's book on Basic complex analysis or Serge Lang's Complex analysis on what is called the Mellin transform.

Comment: @OliverDiaz You are right that I asked it before but i got like 4 different answers which didn't solve my problem. and if you can take a look on the way that i was asked it will be better than suggesting a different one :)

Comment: Here is a link to Lang's: https://books.google.com/books?id=0qx3BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=mellin+transform+serge+lang&source=bl&ots=SU7qTwSSMn&sig=ACfU3U0TrCZ-2yhwC9m9QeH0RdidIv-Mbw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikguju_PnpAhXCSTABHeoBA3kQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=mellin%20transform%20serge%20lang&f=false

Comment: @OliverDiaz thanks :)

Comment: The question should be corrected (why $z=re^{\color{red}{a}\mathrm{i}(2\pi-\epsilon)}$? and "plugging it into $f$" done with mistakes).